# Google Play: Cannot remove country while staged rollout in progress

Tags: google-play, release, production, countries, rollout

Until recently I had an app available in production in 2 countries, but then I decided to stop releasing the app in 1 of the 2 countries.

When I went to release new versions of the app I would only select 1 of the countries and rollout to 100%.

The release dashboard showed the correct version of the app as the most recent release (and stated it was only available in 1 country), but I realised today that an older version of the app was still listed as 'available' in both countries.

I want to remove the app from the the store in the other country completely, but when I go to the 'Countries/regions' tab the 'Remove countries / regions' button is greyed out and there is a message saying "Cannot remove country while staged rollout is in progress".

The staged rollout is already set to 100%. I thought that this would amount to a full rollout, so why am I still seeing this warning message? What can I do to remove the other country from the list?

Answer (score 2):

Not much info out there on this but I finally figured it out!

If you only roll out an update in selected countries (i.e. not every country on your rollout list) then Google Play interprets this as a 'Staged rollout' even if the rollout is set to 100%.

To fix (bizarrely enough) you have to update your most recent release to be available in all countries, refresh the page, and then go to the 'Countries/regions' tab and the 'Remove countries / regions' button should now be active. By clicking that button you'll  be able to remove countries permanently from the list.